# Do Anaconda Cloud packages come with their dependencies?

Tags: python, pip, anaconda, miniconda

Do Anaconda cloud packages manually pulled from their website come with all of the packages dependencies?

For example, I have package A that I need for a python project. It has a dependency tree like below:

```
pip show package_A  
Name: package_A  
Version: 1.0.1  
Requires: package_X, package_Y  

pip show package_X  
Name: package_X  
Version: 2.0.2  
Requires:  

pip show package_Y  
Name:package_Y  
Version: 3.0.3  
Requires: package_M  

pip show package_M  
Name: package_M  
Version: 4.0.4  
Requires:
```

So if I wanted to manually pull down package_A from the anaconda cloud site, would I need to pull the `*.tar.bz2` files for all packages or would the `package_A-1.0.1-py36hafb9ca4_1.tar.bz2` file have all of the dependencies also?

I use pip to show the dependencies, but I will be using conda to install. SOmething like:

```
conda install /libs/package_A-1.0.1-py36hafb9ca4_1.tar.bz2
```

Answer (score 1):

'conda install' command will resolve and install all dependencies automatically provided this was configured within the package.  You can check package dependencies by running -

```
conda info package_A=1.0.1=py36hafb9ca4_1
```

However, if you you install directly from tarballs there is no dependency check. To install local packages you can use the option "--use-local"

```
conda install --use-local package_A=1.0.1=py36hafb9ca4_1
```

Comment: Thank you! In my situation I have to install using local tarballs and I did have to go and get the additional dependencies. I used `conda install /path/to/local/package.tar.bz2/`